# how to add one new attribute in a table

Tags: sql, database, jmeter

I have used `JMETER` to record `CREATE, DELETE` of a table. It is working fine. A new attribute is added in that table after which my execution of `CREATE`, `DELETE` for that table is failed. It gives me error of `invalid identifier(ORACLE/PLSQL: ORA-00904)`

Is there anyway to add the new attribute in the existing table??
Or do I need to re-record `CREATE`, `DELETE` steps?

Comment: Do you use JDBC request for execution you scripts? How did you record it? Please, provide more info

Comment: I have used recording controller to record using HTTP Proxy Server.